# Ошибка в django проекте,не запускается

Tags: python, django, сервер, хостинг, миграция

Делал миграцию на хостинг,сайт django.Вроде все перенес как в [гайде](https://jino.ru/spravka/hosting/articles/django_move.html#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-passenger-wsgi-py).Единственное я не использовал файл passenger_wsgi.py,как я понял в меня в директории mysite лежит wsgi.py темеже настройками как в гайде  с этим файлом passenger_wsgi.py.Не понимаю как мне запустить django проект(
Пытался через python manage.ry runserver ничего не происходит.

На сайте пишет вот это:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.34 Server at watchmerasd.ru Port 80

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]